# iOS - Number of pages in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView that is set to have paging enabled with horizontal scrolling.  The cells within the collection view are simple icons, like you would find on the iOS springboard.  The number of items/cells can vary dynamically, so there is no fixed value.  I'd like to be able to determine the number of pages that will be displayed within the UICollectionView, but it looks as though there is no property exposed that would give me this value.  That said, how can I calculate the number of pages that will be displayed in the collection view?

Comment: If it is 1 cell per page, can't you just look in the datasource for that value? Otherwise you will need to calculate the width of each cell from your datasource, sum that, plus the spacing and divide it by the width of the CollectionView.

Comment: It is not.  It is multiple pages of icons, like you would find on the iOS Springboard.